# ASP.Net MVC 2 - Code for master page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I am newbie in MVC and trying to create application in asp.net mvc2. For the common header and footer i wants to use master pages which are having dynamic content, Can anyone please tell me where is the best place to write code for master page. I am trying to add code behind for master page but I am not sure about what is recommended in this situation.

Comment: What do you mean by "write code for [the] master page"? Views in MVC do not have any code associated with them beyond render logic.

Comment: I means to write code which can help me in displaying data in master page in run-time, just like the code behind does in ASP.NET.

Comment: There is no difference between Master Pages and regular View pages as far as writing `<%=` code is concerned. Please be more specific.

Comment: I am showing some data in master which is actually coming from database. As this is dynamic data and i have to get it from the DB, so i am not sure where exactly i should write business logic for this.

Comment: Do i need to write controller for master also as we do for views?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion,  you can create `partial` views (type of user control) and render it in your master page. Write all the logic to get data from database into `partial` view's action method. You can write action method in any of your controller. ex. You can create a   **Layout** controller  and write action method related to master page. A partial view can also be reusable.

To render your partial view in master page you can write code like :

```
<div><%= Html.Action("Header", "Layout") %></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i will implement it.